# Colocar formato 24hrs no ngx-material-timepicker

Tags: ionic, time

Bom dia, estou tentando colocar este time picker no formato 24h, porém não obtive sucesso, alguém que já tenha usado, saberia como ? Obrigado!

Docs: [Documentação](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker/v/1.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a documentação somente necessário a implementação do format:

ngx-material-timepicker **[format]="24"**

Comment: sim, mas acredito que para versão mais recente, eu estou usando a 1.1.2, pq o angular aqui é antigo, dessa forma não da certo, diz que format não é uma propriedade de ngx-material-timepicker

Comment: Mas na documentação da versão 1.1.2 também diz que tem o formato 24.

Comment: sim, essa é minha dúvida, aqui não está dando certo

Comment: Testei em casa onde tenho ioinic 4 e coloquei a versão mais atualizada do plugin, Deu certo. O problema realmente é a versão, tá difícil char um relógio legal para ionic 3 e angular 5